# Piano in C, issue with sdl sound

Tags: c, audio, sdl

I want to build my own piano in C(1999), but there are some problems with the (sound) output.

The program detects pressed keys, and how long they are pressed...
If a key is pressed, it starts a new `thread(phthread)` which should play a specified *wav* file, and if the key is not pressed anymore the thread will be killed.

*SDL* is loaded in `main()` and the audio device is opened in main to (as global).
But the problem is that SDL keeps playing even if the sound thread is terminated.

So what I want:
A sound function that could play up to 8 sounds at one time, "playing live" (don't load the complete file in to the buffer and start playing), can be initialized globally

Program is for an Arch Linux system, but all-platforms (Unix, OSX, Microsoft Windows) would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you might think that your thread is playing a sound, you shouldn't think of it this way. Your thread made SDL start playing that sound, so if you kill your thread, there is nothing left to stop playing that sound.

You actually don't need threads for this at all:

- when a key is pressed, start a sound on the next free channel.
- keep track of this pair (key, channel)
- if the key is released, look up the (key, channel) pair and call `Mix_HaltChannel` with that specific channel as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Already found it:
Mix_Volume(Channel,Volume)